# What is the obvious advantage of using AMPL?

Tags: netbeans, cplex, ampl

I am doing a project using CPLEX solver, on Netbeans with Java. We have several optimization problems to solve, I have already solved one of them by coding in Java all the constraints, objective and variables, without using AMPL. However, some people in my team want to use AMPL.
Thus, as I don't want to read all the AMPL book to find the answer, is there an obvious reason to rather use AMPL than coding all the constraints "manually"? Moreover, can AMPL be integrated in Netbeans ? I did not find any documentation about that.
Is AMPL useful when the constraints need to be "flexible" (I mean, we can't guess in advance the exact number of constraints, it depends on the parameters fixed by the user, modularity is a high importance factor...)

I am really curious to hear about that soon !

Thanks for help

Answer (score 4):

You have just coded an optimisation model to optimise your company's production of widgets. Your company got a really good deal on $SOLVER1 so that's what you're using.

Over the next ten years, you improve and extend that model as your bosses throw new requirements at you. By the end of that time, you may have tens of thousands of lines of optimisation code as part of a system that, by now, is absolutely critical to your company's operations.

Your company's original licensing deal has expired, and the manufacturers of $SOLVER1 have massively increased the licensing fees, so you're now paying hundreds of thousands a year in licensing costs.

Meanwhile, the boffins at a rival company have just released a new version of $SOLVER2. It has fancy new algorithms that could solve the widget optimisation problem 20% faster and find better solutions than $SOLVER1 is giving you. It doesn't cost any more than $SOLVER1 and the performance is better.

Meanwhile, the open-source community has released $FREESOLVER. It might not be quite as powerful as the top commercial options, but it's as good as $SOLVER1 was ten years ago, and if you weren't paying $100k/year for licensing you could rent an awful lot of server time to make up for it.

...so, did you write your optimisation model on a platform that lets you switch to a new solver and take advantage of these opportunities without having to jettison ten years' worth of code?

There are huge advantages to being able to switch solvers quickly and easily. I know of one company who uses three different solvers for their work: they try two different open-source solvers both running in the cloud, and if neither of those can find an adequate solution *then* they throw it to an expensive solver with smarter algorithms. The open-source solvers handle 90% of their problems, so they only have to use the commercial solver for the last 10%, which allows them to make significant savings on their licensing costs.

One option we've discussed at my work is to use a commercial solver for mission-critical work, and open-source alternatives for applications like training or small-scale prototyping where we don't have the same requirements. That way we can minimise the number of concurrent users we need to license for the commercial solver.

(And, yes, there is still an issue of lock-in with the platform, but platforms like AMPL are *significantly* cheaper than a high-end commercial solver.)

Comment: That scenario is *SO* true. Facing exactly that issue *again* right where I am sitting right now.

Comment: @MysteryGuy Academic projects are easy mode: your objectives are clearly defined, they're unlikely to change, and you don't have to worry about how maintainable your code is. It sounds as if you have a smooth path to passing this project just by using what you already know. But the real point of study isn't to pass assignments by using what you already know; it's to learn *new* things that will be useful in later life. IME, making the shift from "things that work for uni assignments" to "things that work in the workplace" was a huge part of professional development.

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent Thanks, your explanation looks fine :-)

Comment: At https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/optimization-aka-prescriptive-analytics-should-we-write-fleischer/  I gave some pros and cons of AML vs GPL

Answer (score 3):

[AMPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMPL) is an algebraic modeling language and quoting from that link:

> One advantage of AMPL is the similarity of its syntax to the
>   mathematical notation of optimization problems.

For example, this can allow you to define groups of constraints without knowing in advance the dimensions of the model. And, perhaps, you can make big changes to your model more quickly. (You'll have to think about how often you will actually do that.)

However, one could argue that the "obvious advantage" of AMPL is that it supports dozens of different solvers. You can create your model and solve it with CPLEX, but then decide that you want to use a different solver (e.g., Gurobi, Xpress, etc.). On the AMPL [Solvers](http://ampl.com/products/solvers/) web page, they have the following recommendation:

> We recommend that you then test alternative solvers to determine which
>   offers the best tradeoff of price and performance for your needs.

The AMPL [API](http://ampl.com/products/api/) web page says that there is a Java API, so that should allow you to include it in a Netbeans project, but I have no experience with that.

At the end of the day, you could also argue that these "advantages" are a matter of taste. Using the CPLEX Java API directly, as you have already done, is certainly a valid solution if it meets your requirements. It may allow you to build the model more efficiently, use solver-specific/advanced features that might not be supported by AMPL, and to have more fine-grained control over the model formulation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Actually, I do need to use Cplex because it is compulsory. Is AMPL sth hard to learn ?

Comment: Even if you need to use CPLEX *now*, knowing how to write stuff in a solver-independent way is in itself valuable for the future. AMPL (and the other modelling languages like OPL, MPL and so on) are not hard to learn, and using them will give you a different perspective on your model formulation(s).

Answer (score 2):

Totally agree with everything that rkersh says. Also note that you should never write your model in a way that hard-codes details of your problem sizes etc. whether you write in an algebraic modelling language or through one of the more direct APIs.

Also, working with a modelling language gives you an extra level/layer of abstraction which can help, especially in sharing or explaining your model to others, comparing with a range of standard problem types etc., but I prefer the more nuts-and-bolts 'feel' of working with the more direct APIs, and almost never need (or have time & budget) to reformulate my models that deeply.

Answer (score 2):

- Even GPL means "general" yet newer and newer GPLs coming to life, so a given GPL is "more general" to somet tasks than others... :-) In theory writing a compiler the most efficiently for Pascal or Perl should not matter, so in fact you could write in whatever language you want and yet you should not lose expressivity or efficiency (e.g. for C# which is in the same league for Java now, MS writes a better compiler than the opensource equivalent).
- Humans are specializing - this is why we have gotten this far :-) . No different when it comes to achieve a given task to convert a business problem to a math model (aka modeling). The whole idea of having a given modeling layer is that

  - A. you have the outmost expressivity for that particular task (aka math modeling)
  - B. it enforces some best practicies for modeling what in GPL you are not "forced" to do (1. you are free to do 2. it is marketed to you as such = flexibility). E.g. AMPL, GAMS, others are mixing declarative code (aka model code) and procedural code (aka flow-control-like) which is not a good practice. On the other hand e.g. separating data and an abstract model is getting to ALL modeling languages but interestingly enough very slowly...
  - C. thru no.A you can maintain the code more efficiently than otherwise (contrary to API modeling - I have clients who say they turned to modelinglanguage becuase API modeling is a liability for rapid model revamp)
  - D. in theory you could be solver independent.
- If you look around all modeling languages are trying to maintain no.C except OPL (that's for historical reasons). But even in case of OPL, you get constraint-programming and constraint-based scheduling (beside math-programming) what with AMPL/GAMS you don't, however solverindependent they are...
- the $Solver1 and $Solver2 + $Freesolver comparison is a bit broken for 4 reasons

  - A. opensolvers are still very far away from commercial solvers in term of performance when it comes to large/complex problems (probably LP is getting to the exception) - I have clients - the fastest ever sales in my memory - when they tested commercial solvers after their "free-ride".
  - B. while indeed the scenario described in relation with $Solver1 and $Solver2 seems plausible ($Solver1, the incumbent is getting more expensive over time), we could witness just the other way around where the $Solver2 (a new comer) actualy increased its pricing 4x in 7 years and in some cases doubled it, while $Solver1 (the incumbent) has had no change.
  - C. mixing up modeling capabilities and solvers is a mistake. The whole idea is that somebody writes models in APIs IS the way to stick to a solver much more than thru modeling languages. At a minimum, as the Hungarians say "what you gain on the custom you lose it on the ferry", in other words, "freedom (i.e. flexibility) comes with using it responsibly"
  - D. owning a solver for development is NOT expensive at all, i.e. a company can maintain large # of solvers (for less than 10k$ a company could have +4 solvers for development) to test which is the fastest for any given model and then choose the best suited for deployment.
- in addition, solver is just one piece of the puzzle. E.g. I have a client who has disparate data sources and it takes 8hours to create a model and 4hours to solve it. Would this client welcome a more efficient data handling suite or would it insist that the solver should be faster? Modelers are too isolated from the business in most cases and while in their mind a given model is perfect, how it is populated by data is secondary, yet it makes or breaks a good performance.
- I witness that API modelers are moving to modeling languages, not the other way around for various reasons...
- but as somebody wrote above, there are lots of "tastes in the game", so eventually if you feel more confortable with a given approach then nobody can blame you to choose so... :-) after all it is very difficult to compare the/an other approach since it's almost never there on a given case... so eventually what counts is speed from business problem to a model which solve fast in the given application context :-)

phew, it was long... but I gave all my shots... :-)

Comment: Yes, the high-end commercial solvers generally do outperform open solvers by a significant margin, but I'm not sure how this is a counter-argument to the example I gave. For many problems the open solvers are still good enough, and for an organisation that has a mix of easy and hard problems with the same model, being able to do the easy problems on a free solver can be a significant cost reduction.

Answer (score 0):

To keep it short to illustrate advantage/disadvantage of using AMPL just compare using Java(AMPL) instead of assembly language(CPLEX).